# Process used vb.net how to close

Tags: vb.net

```
 Private Sub _LoadAndWrite()
        Dim objWdDoc As Object
        Dim objWord As Object
        objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        objWdDoc = CreateObject("Word.Document")

        Dim regKey As RegistryKey
        Dim path As String

        regKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\tDocManager", True)
        path = regKey.GetValue("DocPath", "")
        Dim DocPath As New System.IO.FileInfo(path)
        regKey.Close()

        Dim FileToCopy As String
        FileToCopy = DocPath.FullName
        NewCopy = DocPath.DirectoryName & "\" & Date.Now.Ticks.ToString & DocPath.Extension

        If System.IO.File.Exists(FileToCopy) = True Then
            System.IO.File.Copy(FileToCopy, NewCopy)
        End If

        objWdDoc = objWord.Documents.Add(NewCopy)
        objWord.Visible = True

        Dim sQ As String = ""
        sQ &= " SELECT ...."

        Dim _cmd As New SqlCommand
        With _cmd
            .CommandText = sQ
            .Connection = dbMain
        End With

        Dim _da As New SqlDataAdapter(_cmd)
        Dim _dt As New DataTable

        Try
            _da.Fill(_dt)
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

        If _dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            For Each dr In _dt.Rows
                With objWdDoc.Bookmarks

                    If .Exists("tt") = True Then
                        .item("tt").Range.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(dr("tt")), "", dr("tt"))
                    End If
                End With
            Next
        End If

End Sub
```

After that i call the function to write to database

```
  Private Sub WriteWordDoc(filename As String, data As Byte())
        Dim fs As New System.IO.FileStream(filename, IO.FileMode.Create)
        Dim bw As New System.IO.BinaryWriter(fs)
        bw.Write(data)
        bw.Close()
        fs.Close()
    End Sub
```

i Got the error the file is used by another process . Even if i try to kill the process it still wont solve the problem.

Where am i making mistake with this ?

Edit> Button click call this

```
If MsgBox("Do you want to generate the document for current job ", MsgBoxStyle.YesNoCancel, "Word document") = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
        _LoadAndWrite()
    End If

If MsgBox("Do you want to save document with changes ", MsgBoxStyle.YesNoCancel, "Word document") = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
    _SaveDocument(NewCopy)
End If

   Public Sub _SaveDocument(ByVal doc2 As String)
        Dim file As String = doc2
        Dim doc() As Byte = ReadWordDoc(file)
End Sub
```

Comment: *Where* do you get the error, in `WriteWordDoc`?

Comment: Yes i forgot to mention that. In first line at WriteWordDoc sub

Comment: Whats the point of the first block of code? It doesnt call `WriteWordDoc` so what are we supposed to glean from it?

Comment: It has the code on button click event. Thread updated

Comment: from `objWord.Documents.Add(NewCopy)`, it looks like Word may still be using it.  I cant see anything to close, release or dispose of it.

Comment: I tried with closing it `objWord.Quit()`  `objWdDoc.Close()`

Comment: Try Marshal: Marshal.ReleaseComObject(objWord).

Comment: Or actually, my apologies.  I call ReleaseComObject on "inner" workings, and FinalReleaseComObject on the app.  If the above didn't work, try calling "Marshall.ReleaseComObject(objWdDoc) and then "Marshall.FinalReleaseComObject(objWord)

Comment: What would be Marshall ? Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error BC30451 'Marshal' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: Anyways that didnt solved the problem. Still {"The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\t3cho\Desktop\635883926280591969.docx' because it is being used by another process."}

Comment: I tried even with killing the word process didnt helped

Comment: Can you edit and add _SaveDocument code?  Or am I just not seeing it?

Comment: @Aaron done see edit

Comment: which block is it in?  I see the call to it in the button click, I see WriteWordDoc, which I assume is called from inside _SaveDocument... I see _LoadAndWrite.. But I don't see the actual code for _SaveDocument.

Comment: On button click it popup the first messagebox. If user accept it will go to function _LoadAndWrite. After that the second messagebox popups. If user accept it call function _SaveDocument. Inside the function _SaveDocument it call the function WriteWordDoc ( Inside WriteWordDOc) it says the file is used

Comment: I believe it probably has to do with NewDoc, not the word object.  But I can't tell how you're operating on NewDoc - maybe after you pull the filename and byte array out of newdoc, try closing it.  Since killing word isn't the issue, NewDoc is probably locked by *your* program, keeping your program from moving on.  But again, without seeing what you're doing, I'm only guessing.

Comment: @Aaron If you are interested to help here is entire class "http://pastebin.com/hSuJ52U7

Comment: I found out what is the problem :) Will update soon

Comment: Post your comment as solution. This fixed problem

  objWdDoc.SaveAs(NewCopy)
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(objWdDoc)
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(objWdDoc)